Which Minhag to follow
I am a baal teshuva who is going to attend a Jewish day school next year. My mother is halachically jewish. My father's status is not so clear. We are sure he has Sefardic ancestry on both sides but we dont know if he is Jewish or not.
I quite literally need to choose which teffileh service I will go to. So which minhag do I follow?

Hello, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! This is a question you should pose to a rabbi. This site isn't for practical halachic advice.

Where will you fit in best? And assuming you'll be attending a synagogue on a regular basis, what's the most common minhag at that synagogue? Think about those practical questions more; obsess less about who did what hundreds of years ago.

Welcome to MiYodeya Ari and thanks for this first question. Your question was closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.
